# How to create a Git commit template with *nix $USER variable in it?

Tags: linux, git

I'd like to add an environment variable to my git commit messages. Eventually, I think I want to make a commit message "template" which would have a few required lines to be filled in when commit'ing. I've tried using a git hook in `/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` consiting of the following, however if you cancel the commit because you forgot something, git mistakes that as your commit message and completes the commit.

```
test -n "$LC_SSH_USER" && echo "Author: $USER" >> "$1"
```

Next, I found an example using the `[commit]` section in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[commit]
  template = .commit_template
```

The contents of my `.commit_template` are below, however simply entering the environment variable in the template does not do what I want. The template pulls in OK, the commit cancels OK, however $USER is inserted literally into the message:

```
Author : $USER

Reason:

Fix:
```

How can I insert an environment variable into a git commit and still be able to cancel the commit?

Comment: Git already captures username and email in commits. Why capture it twice? Seems like that just clutters the message.

Comment: On standard environments this is true (as seen in `git log`). This question involves a device which has an environment that is not quite standard which is why I am trying to find another solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. The username and email are set in git config. Are you saying you somehow can't have a config file?

Comment: if you have an answer to contribute, please post it.

Comment: I'm thinking that if I understood your problem there might be a clean solution for it. For example, the template you posted looks like you're  using git as a bug tracker. However you can link git to actual (free) bug trackers, which is not only standard practice but also maintains the natural hierarchy of problem => multiple commits. And as mentioned git already has a mechanism for capturing user's name....

Comment: You might also want to ask this on [stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/git) or [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). Many git experts there. But...they may ask you similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone else out (and @Diogenes deLight is correct, not the best place for this discussion) I added this to `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.  Any shell variable could be expanded in there to create the commit template.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Author :$USER
Reason :
Issue  :
" > .commit_template
```

Also need this in `.git/config`

```
[commit]
  template = .commit_template
```